# R Markdown cite figure before figure inserted

Tags: r, r-markdown

New to Markdown so trying to navigate. I'm using `bookdown`. I'm trying to work out how to insert an image and but cite it prior to the code.

What I'd like:

> Blablabla (Figure 1). Blablabla bla.
>
> FIGURE.
>
> Caption: Figure 1.

I'm currently doing:

````
![Cholesterol Metabolism](figure/cholesterol metabolism.png)
```{r}
fig_nums <- captioner() 
fig_nums("Cholesterol Metabolism", "CAPTION FOR FIG 1")
```
````

And to cross reference the figure I have

(`r fig_nums("Cholesterol Metabolism", display = "cite")`)

But how can I cross reference before the figure?

Am I also right in thinking that this method will let me insert figures throughout and it will automatically change the number as I go along? So, say I place a figure before the existing Figure 1, it will re-number that figure to Figure 2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to include images using `knitr::include_graphics()` in a code chunk like this:

````r
```{r tiger, fig.cap = "A giant tiger"}
knitr::include_graphics(tiger.png)
```
````

Note that for cross-referencing to work you need to equip the chunk with a name (here `tiger`) and set a caption using `fig.cap`.

You can reference the figure as follows (no matter whether before or after the chunk):

```
Figure \@ref(fig:tiger) shows a tiger.

[This](#fig:tiger) is a tiger. (HTML output only)
```

Note that it might be necessary to *build* the book for the references to work.

[image]

(image from [here](https://pngimg.com/download/23233))

And yes, bookdown ensures that multiple images are numbered correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! In terms of best practice, where is it best to include the initial code chunk?

Comment: I‘m not sure I understand what „the initial code chunk“ is. If you‘re referring to the chunk producing the image: that depends on the document/output type and thus is up to you.